Diophantine equation $a^4+b^4+c^4=2d^2$
Let $a^4+b^4+c^4=2d^2$ such that $a,b,c,d$ are all nonzero integers & $a+b+c$ is non Zero.
I Find four Solutions by Trial & Error
$$(a,b,c,d)=(1,3,10,71),(1,9,22,347),(1,12,41,1193),(2,55,111,8971)$$
I tried to reduce the Variable
$$\frac{a^4}{c^4}+\frac{b^4}{c^4}+\frac{c^4}{c^4}
=\frac{2d^2}{c^4}$$
Put $$x=\frac{a}{c}$$
$$y=\frac{b}{c}$$
& $$z=\frac{d}{c^2}$$
$$x^4+y^4+1=2z^2$$
Now, i Don't have any Idea to solve above equation for Rational Solutions
Already I know, Jacobi - Maiden Identity
$$(a+b)^4 + a^4 + b^4 = 2(a^2+ab+b^2)^2$$
Which solves the case : $a+b+c=0$
Is there any parametrization that gives Infinitely many solutions ?
Is there any Complete Solution ?

@Angelo $2(ab)^2+2(ac)^2+2(bc)^2-a^4-b^4-c^4=(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)$ if we take $a+b+c=0$ or $a+b-c=0$ that gives same Jacobi Maiden Identity because in Lhs terms has an Even power So it works

Guruprasad, since you wrote that $a,b,c,d$ are all positive,  Jacobi-Maiden identity just solves the case $c=a+b$,  not the case $a+b+c=0$ which is impossible if $a,b,c$ are positive or is equivalent to $a=b=c=0 $ if $a,b,c$ are non-negative.

@Angelo, Thank You for finding a mistake in Statement. Now  i edited the statement of the problem

Guruprasad, why did you write that $a+b+c$ is non Zero at the beginning of your post and then you wrote that Jacobi - Maiden Identity solves the case $a+b+c=0$ ? You should be more coherent with yourself.

@Angelo, There are known parameterization solutions for the case $a+b+c= 0$ where a,b,c, are Integers, so i restrict a problem with that condition to get an other parametrization Solutions.

There are 301 co-prime solutions without a+b=c, with $a\lt b\lt c$ and $c<300$ including (3,7,14,143) and (13,15,16,269).  If half the sum is around $c^4$, the chance it is square is around $1/2c^2$, and there are about $c^2/2$ possible pairs $a,b$.  So there may well be a regular supply, even without the known $a+b=c$ ones.

@Empy2 thank you, is it possible to find  any parameterization that gives infinitely many primitive  solutions ?

$(6n^2-2n-1)^4+(6n^2+2n-1)^4+(12n^2+2)^4=2*(108n^4+32n^2+3)^2$.  There may be another with  $(1,12,41),(19,31,96),(49,62,175)$ and $(91,105,278)$.

@Empy2 , how to find these kind of parameterization , Is there any reference  to study these parameterization

I ran a program to find all the solutions with $a\lt b\lt c\le 300$.  I removed those with common factors.  Then I looked at all sets of four solutions.  Where each of a, b and c fit separate quadratics, the program told me.  There were two in the list.  I worked out the first one, and you can work out the other.

Mathematically I know how to generate more solutions  but I don't know how to find a parametrization.

$a=55k, b=2k, c=k, d=2139k^2$ ($k\in \mathbb{N}$) can be one example of parametrization such that $a\neq b+c$ or anything else.

Can you expand on how you found it or why this is the case?

Unfortunately, I just used brute force. I am seeking for generalized solutions.
